# FB like button generating automatical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I have a fb like button on client's website. The issue is that while clicking on the like button it is generating automatically a scroll bar.

**Div class**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-share="false" data-width="88px" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fb-like{float:left; width:100%; padding:10px;}
._51mz ._51m-:first-child{float:left !important;}
._51m-.pls._51mw{float:left!important; width:100%!important; padding-left:0!important; padding-top:5px!important;}
```

I have attached a screen shot for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Sorry friend , this sollution is not working.

Comment: add overflow:hidden to body

Comment: This solution also not working ... :D

Comment: Ok - it's not clear from the *description* of the question what the problem is - can you *describe* where the extra scrollbar appears and what causes it.  Maybe add a 'before' screenshot without the extra scrollbar?

Comment: It looks like you've simply put the 'like' button on the right, but when you click it it becomes wider.  Move the button to the left.

Comment: Yaaa exactly that's the issue dear friend.

Comment: well, then do that. you should never place like buttons in the right corner.

Comment: But this is a client's requirement; so what can i do ??? :D

Comment: That flyout that appears to let the user input a comment on their like simply takes more space than you are giving it - so the only _proper_ solution is to place the element somewhere where it can take that space to begin with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_108505412905717